# Who can access a device's local storage?

Tags: security, backbone.js, local-storage, device, phonegap

From what I could find, I concluded that local storage is not to be trusted with sensitive information, even on a mobile / tablet.

However, could someone explain how the local storage information can be leaked on an app running on a device ?

The application I'm working on is using backbone and phonegap and I need to know how easily one can access the local storage.

For example, can someone access the local storage of the user without touching the user's device (by touching, I mean having actual physical access to the device) ? Assuming that the device can be connected to a wireless LAN and a potential attacker can also be connected to the same network.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One can access it if he can inject and run scripts in your application

Comment: Can he inject scripts to the application without 'making' the user take some actions from his side ? For example, does the injection needs the user to install something or download something ? Or it can be done without the user's own actions.

Comment: Nothing can be done without "any" action from the user. But user might be tricked into performing some action without him knowing, especially when it comes to web applications on browser.  But this is very unlikely for a mobile app, unless your app  provide options to open external content, and does not validate the external input etc.